# Regex find and replace specific element from string

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I need some help

I have string from my `innerHTML` div

```
<div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-1">
     <div class="class-bla-bla class-find">Replace this div</div>
     <div class="class-another">Hello World!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="class-2">

       <div class="class-2 class-find">Replace this div</div>
       <div class="class-no-replace">No replace</div>

    </div>
    <div class="class-somthing class-find">Replace this div</div>

</div>
```

and I want to use regex to find and replace all element with `class name class-find` and store the innerHTML string into database without change the actual HTML DOM, I tried to find the solution but I can not find any good answer for my case, please give me a favor to solve this out.

Note: I have found some sample regex https://www.regextester.com/93456, this only work if the element only have one class not multiple.

Comment: Why not use standard DOM manipulation instead, such as with `querySelector`? Better not to try to parse non-trivial HTML with regex

Comment: _Don't_ use regex for this please.  JavaScript is an efficient HTML parser, use it for this.

Comment: Because I want store the replaced string into db but not change the actual DOM html view :)

Comment: Then use `DOMParser` and continue to use DOM manipulation methods.

Comment: Perhaps you need to better explain your problem / what you are looking to do, because "_I want store the replaced string into db but not change the actual DOM html view_" is not a valid reason to use regex over DOM manipulation.  There is nothing regex can do that DOM manipulation can't. But there's plenty DOM manipulation can do that regex can't.

Comment: Also using regex to scrape the html content and replace something _is_ DOM manipulation - just not with built-in DOM manipulation methods!

Answer (score 2):

As regex is not meant to parse HTML. You can use the `DOMParser` API for the purpose.

```js
let d = new DOMParser();
let s = `<div class="class-1">
<div class="class-1">
 <div class="class-bla-bla class-find">Replace this div</div>
 <div class="class-another">Hello World!</div>
</div>

<div class="class-2">

   <div class="class-2 class-find">Replace this div</div>
   <div class="class-no-replace">No replace</div>

</div>
<div class="class-somthing class-find">Replace this div</div>

</div>`;
let doc = d.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
let divs = doc.querySelectorAll('.class-find');
let html = [];
divs = divs.forEach(e => {
  html.push(e.innerHTML);
});
console.log(html);
```